# Subconsulta sin INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla cliente (id, nombre, apellido) y una tabla pedido (id, cantidad, fecha, id_cliente), ¿cómo puedo sacar los datos del cliente que realizó el pedido más barato en una fecha determinada?
No puedo usar INNER JOIN, sólo subconsultas.
Si uso el MAX(cantidad) en el SELECT obtengo una cifra, pero necesito que devuelva todos los campos para luego poder comparar la id del cliente.

Edito para poner lo que estoy intentando. El código ha de ser con consultas anidadas, y mi bloqueo mental ha derivado en este horror:

```
SELECT *
FROM cliente c
WHERE c.id=(SELECT pedido.id_cliente
            FROM pedido
            WHERE (SELECT MIN(cantidad)
                    FROM pedido
                    WHERE (SELECT *
                            FROM pedido
                            WHERE year(fecha)=1999
                    )
            )
);
```

Comment: Edito. A veces el código es vergonzante y prefiero no ponerlo :S

Comment: Antes de corregir todo: si es "el pedido más barato", ¿es `MAX` o `MIN`?

Comment: ¿Conocés `HAVING`? No olvides revisar la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html).

Comment: Agrupas los pedidos por id_cliente y lueg aplicas un HAVING ¿con qué condición? Creo que tengo que usar la función MAX(), pero no sé dónde meterla...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asi de primeras, deprisa y corriendo se me ocurre esto

```
select c.* from clientes c, pedidos p where c.id = p.id_cliente and year(p.fecha) = 2022 order by cantidad LIMIT 1;
```

O si lo prefieres con subconsulta

```
select c.* from clientes c where c.id = (
select p.id_cliente from pedidos p where year(fecha) = 2022  group by id_cliente order by cantidad limit 1);
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Como correctamente apunta capovawi en su comentario hay un problema con la sentencia en caso de que haya varios clientes con un pedido mínimo.

La consulta que creo resultaría correcta en todos los escenarios es

```
select c.* from clientes c, pedidos p where c.id = p.id_cliente and p.fecha = '2022-01-01' and p.cantidad = 
    (select min(p2.cantidad) from pedidos p2 where p2.fecha = '2022-01-01');
```

Comment: Dice "fecha determinada": no necesariamente debe ser de este año.

Comment: He utilizado como referencia la consulta que pone de ejemplo. Es cuestión entonces de dejar el campo 'fecha' a secas en el WHERE y poner qué fecha busca.

Comment: ¿qué sucede si hay 2 clientes con el pedido más caro? "LIMIT  1" sólo dejaría que saliera uno de ellos.